# Count percentage of filled inputs inside div

Tags: javascript, html

is there some simple way to count percentage of filled inputs inside a div?
It has to be in **Javascript**, not jQuery.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="content-menu">                                      
 <ul>
  <li id="tab1"><a id="a1">General</br><p> x % FILLED </p></a></li>
  <li id="tab2"><a id="a2">Contact info</br><p> x % FILLED </p></a></li>
 </ul>
</div> 

<div id="tabs-1">
 <input type="text" name="first_name" />
 <input type="text" name="last_name" />
</div>

....
```

So basically if I enter only first name, which is 1/2 out of inputs, it should echo in that li element 50%.
Each tab will have different number of inputs and own filled percenage.

Is it possible with only Javascript?

Any help would be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I would recommend trying but also to stand on the shoulders of giants, jquery.  Unless this is for homework so you can't.  Other options to jquery I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you could get all the input fields inside a `div`. Then you could see how many they are. Later you could count how many of them has a value. Using these two numbers you can get what you want.

```
// Get the div you want to look in.
var div = document.getElementById("tabs-1");

// Get all the input fields inside your div
var inputs = div.getElementsByTagName('input');

// Get the number of the found inputs.
var totalInputs = inputs.length;

// Loop through them and check which of them has a value.
var inputsWithValue = 0;
for(var i=0; i<totalInputs; i++)
    if(inputs[i].value!=='')
        inputsWithValue +=1;     

// Calculate the percentage.
var filledPercentage = (inputsWithValue/totalInputs)*100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a fiddle with instant update of percentage: http://jsfiddle.net/39xdvo96/1/

```
<div class="content-menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab1"><a id="a1">Percentage<br/><p id="percentage">0%</p></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
  var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (i = 0; i < getInputs.length; i++) {

        getInputs[i].onkeyup = function () {

            var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var vals = [].map.call(elem, function (input) {
                return input.value;
            });

        var filteredvals = vals.filter(function(val) {
        return !(val === "" || typeof val == "undefined" || val === null);
        });

            document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = filteredvals.length/(elem.length) * 100 +"%";


        };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some small issues with @Michelangelo answer. There is a missing declaration of i variable and the percentage is not calculated correctly. Here is a fix.

```
// calculate percentage od filled inputs
const inputContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('zk-form')[0];
const getInputs = inputContainer.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

for (let i = 0; i < getInputs.length; i++) {

    getInputs[i].onkeyup = function () {

        let elem = inputContainer.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');
        let vals = [].map.call(elem, function (input) {
            return input.value;
        });

        let filteredvals = vals.filter(function (val) {
            return !(val === "" || typeof val == "undefined" || val === null);
        });
        document.getElementById('zk-submit-percentage').innerHTML = Math.round(filteredvals.length * 100 / (elem.length)) + "%";
    };

}
```